# How to select (highlight) answers or questions text in superuser without using a mouse?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently I started learning to use keyboard shortcuts almost for everything I'm doing on the laptop (os win7) but soon enough after I started, I bumped into the problem of being unable to highlight (select) simple text in the Stack Exchange sites (where I stay almost all the time). I did some research and I couldn't find any solution to my problem. Have I missed an already answered question that is the same like mine or if not what solution can you suggest in order to achieve the results I want without touching mouse or touchpad or any cursor moving device?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are currently using a GUI based browser (Chrome, IE etc.), you probably want to switch to using a keyboard based browser (such as [Conkeror](http://www.conkeror.org/)). To quote the web page:

> **About Conkeror**
>
> Conkeror is a *keyboard-oriented*, highly-customizable,
>   highly-extensible web browser based on Mozilla XULRunner, written
>   mainly in JavaScript, and inspired by exceptional software such as
>   Emacs and vi. *Conkeror features a sophisticated keyboard system,
>   allowing users to run commands and interact with content in powerful
>   and novel ways*. It is self-documenting, featuring a powerful
>   interactive help system.

I have added the italics to highlight why it could meet your needs. It works on most OSes, including Windows.

Here is a tutorial on how to copy text, in Conkeror, from the [MIT Conkeror Tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/nelhage/arch/i386_rhel4/conkeror/content/tutorial.html)

> **Copying Text**
>
> Gecko has a feature called caret browsing that gives you a blinking
>   cursor that you can move and select document text with the keyboard.
>   To enter caret browsing mode in Conkeror, first press C-M-q to enter
>   content-buffer-quote-input-mode. All of your keystrokes until you
>   press ESC will bypass Conkeror's key handling and be passed directly
>   to Gecko. In content-buffer-quote-input-mode you can enter caret
>   browsing mode by pressing F7. Move the caret with up, down, left,
>   right, and so on. Select text by holding shift while moving the caret.
>   Exit caret browsing mode by pressing F7 again. Press ESC to exit
>   content-buffer-quote-input-mode. Press M-w to copy the selection to
>   the clipboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm searching for solutions working with chrome but your post helped indeed a friend of mine who is also interested in using mostly his keyboard, so thanks! Anyway if you know any extension for chrome that would help me achieve what I want I'm open to suggestions.